# How can I change the default application that archive manager uses?

Tags: filemanager

When I had installed the rar application the archive manager was using that one which had problems with non-english characters. I uninstalled it and the archive manager used p7zip. The question is how can I make the archive manage  (and extract here) to use the p7zip instead of rar but have both installed at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to associate p7zip with `.rar` file types. To do so find a `.rar` file and Right Click that file and choose "Open With Other Application..."

[image]

In the "Other Application" menu select "Use a custom command" and enter `/usr/bin/p7zip -d` and check the "Remember this application" checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is valid for ElementaryOS as well.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I found that the best archive manager which support non-English characters is PeaZip [PeaZip web site](http://www.peazip.org/index.html). It has a support for RAR archives and is able to do many other operations.

In order to make this (or other) archive manager as a default choice: from file (archive) Properties menu select a Default application (for current file type).